# Space between print and round brackets

Tags: pycharm

I am using Pycharm Professional 2019.2 and I noticed that it automatically insert a space between print statement and it's round brackets.

[image: print]

I don't like this and I want to use the classic print synthax "print()" instead of "print ()". In 2017 version (last I used before the new build) it was ok.

I already check my settings in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python -> Spaces and for me it's okay. I am doing something wrong ?

[image: settings]

I also see that the IDE suggest to put a whitespace in `def __init__(self)` according to PEP8.

[image: pep8]

Thanks

Comment: I'm running 2019.2 as well and do not see this problem. My Code style settings look exactly the same.

Comment: I have to say that, when upgrading from 2017 I imported the settings..

Comment: Are there no other plugins that may affect this behaviour? Also, does it only occur for print(), or for other builtins as well? Pycharm makes a difference between method declaration and method call (see code style 'before parentheses'). -- And one more question to consider: Is the python file you are editing classed / recognized as a python file?

Comment: The file is a Python one (2.7). Checking/unchecking "Before parentheses" options doesn't change anything. I really don't know about pluggins because I have nearly none installed.

Comment: Checking and unchecking "Method call parentheses" should at least change "return globals()" to "return globals ()" in the code style example window

Comment: Does PEP 8 changed recently ? PyCharm tells me even for a "def __init__(self)" to put a space before parentheses.

Comment: I think pep8 says *not* to put a space in between the method and the parenthesis https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements

Comment: You're right, it seems strange also to me.. I submitted a bug report.

Comment: I'd recommend to e-mail pycharm support. I've found them very responsive that way.

Comment: It doesn't suggest to put a whitespace before `(`, this message says you currently have whitespace and you shouldn't.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov funny thing. There was a space, ok. I leaved it, the warn disappeared and I used "Auto-format" (Ctrl-Alt-L) and the IDE put the space again, but without warning this time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used the new IDE version with a project created with older one.
Creating a new project does not make this strange behaviour to happen.

[Space between print and round brackets](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006369379-Space-between-print-and-round-brackets) <--- here you can find more details.

UPDATE: I forgot to import `print_function` from `__future__`